# android studio 3.4.1 emulator not launching

Tags: android, android-studio

I've successfully installed Android Studio 3.4.1 but when I launch the AVD emulator, it gives me the error `PROCESS FINISHED WITH EXIT CODE 3`

**AM USING WINDOWS 10 PRO, MAY 2019 UPDATE and here are my system specs**

[system specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf5Lb.png)

I've tried all possible solutions including installing older versions but the same problem persists. Below is the error screen.

```
1:57 PM Emulator: H:\ANDROID_DEV\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHPX: Failed to emulate MMIO access with EmulatorReturnStatus: 2 (InternalEmulationFailure )

1:57 PM Emulator: H:\ANDROID_DEV\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: whpx_vcpu { emulator=000000002b2e9930, window_registered=false, interruptable=true, tpr=0, apic_base=fee00900, interruption_pending=false }

1:57 PM Emulator: H:\ANDROID_DEV\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHV_MEMORY_ACCESS_CONTEXT { Instruction={ size=16, bytes='A1 F0 00 E0 FE 80 CC 01 A3 F0 00 E0 FE C7 05 50 ' }, AccessInfo={ AccessType=0, GpaUnmapped=1, GvaValid=0, AsUINT32=4 }, Gpa=fee000f0, Gva=0 }

1:57 PM Emulator: H:\ANDROID_DEV\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHPX: Failed to exec a virtual processor

1:57 PM Emulator: Warning: QMutex: destroying locked mutex ((null):0, (null))

1:57 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 3
```

Comment: It does not appear you have `Windows Hypervisor Platform` currently installed.  Please verify you have all requirements for the Android Studio emulator installed.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate which version of Windows 10 you are using.  Please use `winver` to get the required vital information necessary to answer to this question.  If you are using a AMD processor that is relevant information

Comment: hi, the question has been edited

Comment: It’s very likely you have ran into a compatibly issue with Hypervisor Platform and AMD hardware.  I have seen more than 5 questions all with similar problems.  The Github discussions I have found indicate 20H1 does not have this problem.  However, I cannot suggest, using an Insider Preview build, that is more than 10 months away from being released.